# Ruby in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, helper

I am making a helper for some clipboard copy code. I would like the clipboard to copy a url that is generated in the view.

For example, here is the link that works in the view:

```
<%= link_to event_path(event.id) %>
```

It works just fine in the view. I am having a hard time figuring out where to put it for the helper.  I am passing a variable in my helper, so should I put it in the view and pass it to the variable or should I put it in the helper?  Right now it's in the helper and I get normal text back.

Here is the helper.rb file:

```
def clipboard_copy(text = nil, bgcolor='#FFFFFF')
  html = <<-EOF
        ...
    <param NAME="FlashVars" value="text=#{text}">
           ...
           FlashVars="text=#{text}"
           ...
EOF
html.html_safe
end
```

and I am calling it from the view with:

```
<%= clipboard_copy %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling this in the view?
<%= clipboard_copy(event_url(event.id)) %>

Comment: I am calling it in the view with <%= clipboard_copy %> - sorry, clarifying question.

Comment: Just tried <%= clipboard_copy(event_url(event.id)) %> and it copies:<%= clipboard_copy(event_url(event.id)) %>

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It was a stupid mistake on me! I had the helper in the wrong helper file! Moved it to the right helper file and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it doesn't really need a helper method - have you tried putting it in a partial, passing the text (and, I guess, the bgcolor) as locals to that partial?